# Problems of transcription

Tags: hebrew

mispar hekhrachi is the standard gematria method. But I can not find out which Hebrew word is behind the transcription „hekhrachi“. Can you provide any help?

Comment: The Hebrew is מספר הכרחי

Comment: I don't know what you are asking about -- computer coding? Gematria? Is this related to Judaism or just the Hebrew for absolute value?